# Does logical consequence in classical logic assume finitely many premises/conclusions?

Tags: logic

In logic one often reads $\Gamma \vdash$ A or $\Gamma \vDash$ A. Can one assume in classical logic (PL, FOL, Higher Predicate Logic, Modal Logic) that $\Gamma$ always is a set of finitely many statements, i.e. $\Gamma$ = {$p_{1}, …, p_{n}$} (as well as A if A stands for a set of statements)? I think so because how could we or a computer handle infinitely many statements? We‘d never be able to mechanically prove something or to check semantically if from infinitely many premises something actually follows. Am I right?

Comment: $\Gamma$ **can** be infinite. See e.g. f-o Peano axioms, where Induction is a schema, i.e. an infinite collection of formulas.

Comment: So it is false when I sometimes see $\Gamma \vdash$ A explained as $p_{1}, …, p_{n}$ $\vdash$ A? How would you put it?

Comment: I think Peano Axioms give infinitely many Conclusion Statements , while the Axiom Statements [ Premises Statements ] are very few , @MauroALLEGRANZA , I have not seen theories with infinite axioms !

Comment: Proofs with infinitely many lines? Do you have an actual application in mind?

Comment: @DanChristensen - not a proof with infinitely mani lines, but a proof with an infinite collection (recursive generated) of premises. See [First-order Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory): "In addition to this list of numerical axioms, Peano arithmetic contains the induction schema, which consists of a recursively enumerable and even decidable set of axioms. For each formula φ(x, y1, ..., yk) in the language of Peano arithmetic, the first-order induction axiom for φ is the sentence..."

Comment: And see [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/#WhatSche): "Some mathematical theories can be finitely axiomatized in a first-order language, but certain historically important number theories and set theories cannot. The axioms of these theories can sometimes be specified using schemata. For example, in first-order number theory the induction principle is specified using the schema $[F(0) \land ∀x((Num(x) \land F(x))→F(sx)]→∀x(Num(x)→F(x))$ where ..."

Comment: So when I see things like $\Gamma \vdash$ A or $\Gamma \vDash$ A how do you write down best: $\Gamma$ = {$p_{1}, p_{2}$, …} or $\Gamma$ = {$p_{1}, p_{2}$, …, $p_{n}$}?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily always finite. Note that if  $\Gamma \vDash$ A and for any other set of formulas $\Sigma$ such that $\Gamma \subseteq \Sigma$ then $\Sigma \vDash$ A (this metatheorem is called the *monotonicity of entailment*), and $\Sigma$ need not be finite.

Comment: (1) I think this is not true. Eg We can have $S \in A$ & $\lnot S \in \Sigma$ , then $\Gamma$ is consistent while $\Sigma$ is not consistent. (2) Checking consistency over infinite Statements will involve certain complications. (3) Instead of Peano Axioms , we can not have $N \equiv \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ which is like infinite axiom list.

Comment: I'm not sure what your first point is supposed to say. You do remember that an inconsistent set entails any formula, right? So if $\Gamma$ entails $B$ and $A \in \Gamma$, then if $\Sigma = \Gamma \cup \{ \sim A\}$ then $\Sigma$ also entails $B$.

Comment: That is Exactly what I said in my Point (1) earlier. Using this argument alone is not enough to then claim that we can have infinite Premises. Hard to imagine how we can even list those Premises !

Comment: Well we can't list them if they're infinite. In practice we work with finite premise sets, but the mathematical logic theorem I mention guarantees existence of entailments from infitite sets of premises. That, I thought is directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Consider it this way : [[ Do you have Example where we have infinite Premises , listed or unlisted ? Do you have a Conclusion $X$ in that ? Can you Prove that we can never get $\lnot X$ with those infinite Premises ? ]] : That is not trivial !

Comment: I have an example, but I suspect you may not be satisfied. Nevertheless, I can't think of a better one at the moment. Consider propositional logic and the (infinite) set of all propositional variables $\Pi$ (atomic sentences/formulas, i.e. formulas that do not have any internal propositional structure). That is, $\Pi = \{p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},...\}$. There's a theorem (regarding positive formulas) stating that $\Pi$ is consistent, so we can rule out anything following from it. Now, since $p_{1} \in \Pi$ it follows that $\Pi \vdash p_{1}$ but it's not the case that $\Pi \vdash \sim p_{1}$.

Comment: Your suspicion is right about that not satisfying me. On one side , it is trivial + not interesting & no deep theorems will come out of it. On other side , it is not clear whether the set of all variables exists ( similar to the set of all sets ) & it is not clear whether some new variables $P,X,Y,Z$ can come up & whether everything is vacuously true & whether there is something not true. MSE is warning about commenting : I will conclude this Discussion with this Comment !

Answer (score 0):

No. $\Gamma$ can be infinite.

Just because we can't practically handle the infinite doesn't mean we can't think and make statements about the infinite. So yes, we can't actually generate or check a proof with infinitely many premises, but we can still mathematically think about such proofs.

Comment: We can think about such cases hypothetically , though we will not have Consistent theorems $X,Y,Z$ there , because we can never Prove that we cannot Derive $\lnot X, \lnot Y, \lnot Z$ within that !!

Comment: @Prem note that an set kf axiom schemata for a theory $T$ is a set of formulas. This set is infinite, but we can still draw conclusions from it.

Comment: What I am hinting at : When we get some Conclusions $X,Y,Z$ using finite elements of infinite Set , we can not know whether some other elements might give $\lnot X,\lnot Y,\lnot Z$ or not. When we get some way to Summarize all other elements to Prove that that will not occur , @PW_246 , then we have already replaced infinite Set with fiinte Summary !